# jQuery specify between multiple textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-5, shopping-cart

I'm making a shopping cart for multiple items in a database but after adding a textbox and adding `var quantity` the code only understands the first textbox and adds that quantity for all the other add to cart links.

How do I tell the program to find a specific textbox based on the item it is associated with, just like the line below it that finds the item based on the `'data-id'`.

I've tried using `$(".qty-txt").children().value()` but I still don't know how to specify which Anchor tag to find.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        $(".AddLink").click(function () {
            var quantity = $("#qty").val();
            var recordToAdd = $(this).attr("data-id");
            if (recordToAdd != '') {
                $.post("/ShoppingCart/AddToCart", { "id": recordToAdd, "qty": quantity },
                    function (data) {
                        $('#cart-status').text(data.CartCount);
                    });
                }
             });
        });
</script>
```

The first 3 lines are my Texbox in the anchor tag (would prefer not to use anchor tag if possible)

The second anchor tag is my Link to Add to cart.

```
<a class="qty-txt" data-id="@item.ID">
@Html.TextBox("Quantity", 1, new { @class = "qty-input", @id = "qty", size = 1 })
</a>
<a href="#" class="AddLink" data-id="@item.ID" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      Add to cart
</a>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Are you asking how to target the instance of `.qty-txt` immediately before the `.AddLink` that was clicked? It would help if you'd simplify and only show relevant, client-side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generating invalid html by including duplicate `id` attributes using

```
@Html.TextBox("Quantity", 1, new { @class = "qty-input", @id = "qty", size = 1 })
```

And `var quantity = $("#qty").val();` will only ever return the value of the first element with `id="qty"`

You need to use `new { id = "", ...}` to remove the `id` attribute or just create the textbox manually using

```
<input type="text" class="qty-input" size = "1" value="1" />
```

Then wrap the textbox and the "Add to cart" link in a container so you can use relative selectors (not sure why you wrap the textbox in another `<a>` tag?)

```
<div class="product">
  <input type="text" class="qty-input" size = "1" value="1" />
  <a href="#" class="AddLink" data-id="@item.ID" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add to cart</a>
</div>
```

The modify the script to

```
$('.AddLink').click(function () {
  var quantity = $(this).closest('.product').find('.qty-input').val();
  var recordToAdd = $(this).data('id'); // correct usage to access data- attributes

  if (recordToAdd != '') { // not sure why you need this (why would it ever be null?)
    $.post("/ShoppingCart/AddToCart", { "id": recordToAdd, "qty": quantity }, function (data) {
      $('#cart-status').text(data.CartCount);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much this solved my problem.
Sorry if my code and my question was unclear.
This was my first time ever using jquery.
Again thank you been stuck on this part of the website for days now.

Answer (score 0):

Just select `$(".qty-input")` to get all the matching inputs. Otherwise, you're selecting the list of wrapper elements...if you went that way, then you need to navigate using loops on each instance of the wrapper object(s).

Comment: It is a webpage with 10 items on each page.
Each page has 10 textboxes and 10 addtocart links
using $(".qty-input") only uses the quantity that is inserted in the first textbox for all addtocart links.
I need the website to understand based on which link is clicked which textbox quantity to grab the value from.

If there is any more code or information needed feel free to ask
Thanks for your answer and any future help in advance.